# how to change www-data@ip-x.x.x.x.us-west-2.compute.internal to from email in aws ec2 instance

Tags: php, email, amazon-ec2, header, smtp

I am running my website on AWS EC-2 instance. I have **ubuntu** with **apache2** installed on it.

I am sending email via **PHP** mail function, I am correctly using headers to send from email with info@mydomain.com but it still sending email from 
***www-data@ip-x.x.x.x.us-west-2.compute.internal***

I want to change it please tell me how to do that. I am using below code of PHP to send email

```
   $headers = 'From: Akash <akash@gmail.com>' . "\r\n" ;
and $this->config->item('from_email') = 'akash@gmail.com'
```

Comment: From: John Doe <john.doe@example.com>

Comment: @CatalinB I didnt get you

Comment: `$headers = 'From: [Name of the webmaster]'.'<webmaster@example.com>'. "\r\n"`

Comment: No I am already using from which is fine issue is with AWS ec2 instance.

Comment: It isn't being used correctly. Headers like from need a name and email to be valid.

Comment: The updated question is still using it incorrectly. Try  `$headers = 'From: Akash <akash@gmail.com>' . "\r\n" ;`

Comment: @jedifans I have updated again, please check that by mistake updated wrong last time sorry for that, still getting email from www-data